# Sorting top votes in a timeframe using "Vote it up" and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, digg

I'm building a Digg-like voting site for Christmas greetings. I'm using WordPress and the "Vote it up" plugin. I am having a lot of troubles being able to sort the vop votes within a timeframe.

You can see what I mean on this site; http://wordtaps.com/ Look at the timeframe on the top right, that's exactly what I want. The site also uses the "Vote it up" plugin along with WordPress.

There are a couple of functions on the "vote it up" plugin page which I assume would work, but I just keep on getting errors when I try to use them as I know very little PHP.

My site is www.dinjulehilsen.no (it's in Norwegian)

Comment: Excuse me for disturbing, but could you please share your solution, please? :) i am trying to make a page with top posts using the same plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For sorting top votes using voteitup and wordpress, you can try it: [Show top voted post in index page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/345017). It works in my own social bookmarking nestdev.com